# Devise not allowing sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am installing devise on a Rail 5 application. I'm just doing out-of-the-box. No fancy installation other than fixing up the generated views.

Devise is not letting my users log in to the application. I first encountered the issue when trying to create a new user. I got the error:

```
1 error prohibited this user from being saved:
Email can't be blank
```

But my email is not blank. So I tried created a user from rails c. The user stuck. It shows up in my database. But when I try to sign in through devise, I get this error:

```
Invalid Username or password.
```

It is valid. I don't know what is going on. Here is my schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

Here is the new user view:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1">
 <h3>Sign up</h3>
 <br />

 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

I can definitely confirm there is one user in my database. I don't know what's going on. As far as I can tell, I did nothing out of the ordinary setting this up. Help!

Comment: What does your controller look like? Likely an issue with parameters.

Comment: I have no custom controller. I'm just using whatever devise has running in the background.

Comment: Did you decorate your user model with the devise attributes?  Something is not wired up as devise expects.

Comment: No, this is really weird. I have literally touched nothing in the models. I retouched the views. I changed absolutely nothing to do with logic.

Comment: Show your model.  It likely needs to be touched.

Comment: class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         
end

Comment: Since you were able to work with the model directly, I suspect this has to do with strong parameters.  Check out this, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters.  Might also help to check out the logs to see if there are more hints as to the issue.